# Trouble injecting a value into inner class with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a private static inner class that I need to inject a value into and I am having no luck.

My code's pattern is as follows:

```
@Component
public final class someClassUtil {

    @Component
    private static class innerClass {
        private transient boolean myVar;

        @Value("${my.value.to.inject}")
        public void setMyVar(final boolean myVar) {
            this.myVar = myVar;
        }
    } 
}
```

I have a feeling that it may have something to do with the access modifiers, but I have tried many variants with no success. Any thoughts?

Comment: it would be nice if you post exception stack trace

Comment: There is no exception thrown, myVar simply is not injected and contains the default of false. @AdamSkywalker

Comment: Spring writes logs during context startup, review them to see the causes

Answer (score 0):

Since your nested class is private, I fear that Spring's DI mechanism is not able to invoke the setter thus rendering the annotation on it useless.

Comment: Dang, I was really hoping that was it, but after changing it I still get false instead of injecting true.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`@Value` docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html), you need to use `@Value("#{my.value.to.inject}")`. Note the "#" instead of "$".